# Check if valid date in PostgreSQL source

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, validation, date

I have a remote PG data source where I cannot create custom functions.  I have to dump PG data into unicode tables on MSSQL Server 2008 R2.  I need an inline PostgreSQL statement that would replace an invalid date with something like '1900-01-01'.

I've done extensive googling to no avail ... thanks.

Comment: If it is a date, it cannot be an invalid date.

Comment: I am seeing something like '0214-06-19 00:00:00' in PG, which fails with an overflow error when inserting into SQLServer datetime.

Comment: '0214-06-19 00:00:00' is a valid timestamp. PostgreSQL timestamps cover a much greater range than SQL Server datetimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a much greater range for timestamps than SQL Server does for datetimes. In PostgreSQL, '0214-06-19 00:00:00' is a valid timestamp. So is '0214-06-19 00:00:00 BC'.

It's not clear to me whether the result should be a date or a timestamp. But this shows how you should probably approach the problem in PostgreSQL

```
with data (ts) as (
  values (timestamp '0214-06-19 00:00:00'), ('1900-01-01 08:00')
)
select 
    ts as source_ts, 
    case when ts < timestamp '1900-01-01' then timestamp '1900-01-01' 
         else ts 
    end as altered_ts
from data;
```

```
source_ts             altered_ts
--
0214-06-19 00:00:00   1900-01-01 00:00:00
1900-01-01 08:00:00   1900-01-01 08:00:00
```

Assuming every date before 1900 should be 1900-01-01 is kind of risky. The value '0214-06-19' is probably a typo for 2014-06-19.

Answer (score 0):

More complex algorithms in SQL are easier to write (and read) with CTE:

```
with 
    syntax as (
        select str, 
            str ~ '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$' as syntax_ok,
            split_part(str, '-', 1) as syy,
            split_part(str, '-', 2) as smm,
            split_part(str, '-', 3) as sdd
        from test_date),
    toint as (
        select *,
            case when syntax_ok then syy::int else 1900 end yy,
            case when syntax_ok then smm::int else 1 end mm,
            case when syntax_ok then sdd::int else 1 end dd
        from source),
    semantics as (
        select *,
            case
            when mm in (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) then dd between 1 and 31
            when mm in (4,6,9,11) then dd between 1 and 30
            when mm = 2 then 
                case when yy/4*4 = yy and (yy/100*100 <> yy or yy/400*400 = yy)
                then dd between 1 and 29
                else dd between 1 and 28 end
            else false end as valid
        from toint),
    result as (
        select str,
            case when syntax_ok and valid then str
            else '1900-01-01' end as date
        from semantics)
select * from result
```

The first query checks syntax and split `str` into three parts, the second query casts the parts as integers, and the third query checks semantics.
[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bd2c9/4).

Your comment shows that you do not need quite as thoroughly checks, but I think that this query can be easily customized to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Cast to char and then format how you would like

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date_time_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS mssql_date_format
FROM table_name 
WHERE -- your condition here

-- results like: 1900-01-01
```

Read more here

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html